# In node-red how can I send a message to the debug tab with out using debug node? Is there method I could call

Tags: node-red

[image: Node-RED flow]

I dont want use debug node. rather I want to just pass the debug message to the debug tab directly from my customized node. So I was wondering if may be there is a method that I could use to achieve this.

Comment: Why do you not want to use a debug node?

Answer (score 16):

The `node` object is exposed in the context of a function node and had 2 functions that will add something to the debug tab

`node.warn()` and `node.error()` both print to the debug tab (and also to the console) but with suitable colours and header messages e.g.

```
node.warn(msg.payload);
return msg;
```

[image: warn and error messages in debug tab]

Be aware that node.error will also raise a message that can be caught by the *Catch* node so if you just want to report status from with in a function then the `node.warn` is probably best

Comment: Once a `node.error()` is invoked, should it be followed with a `return null` statement to halt the flow? Or, will that happen on its own?

Comment: That entirely depends on the context of where it was called

Comment: An example, please?

Comment: It's bad that there is no node.debug

Comment: @Xdg There is a `node.debug()` but it is not for sending items to the sidebar. https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/writing-functions#logging-events

Answer (score 0):

You can use the context store of the node.

in Start of node :

```
if(context.get("errors") === undefined) {
    context.set("errors", [])
}
```

in Function of node :

```
context.get('errors').push({
   status: 'err',
   message: 'There is an error',
   ts: new Date(),
   details: {
       no: '001'
   }
})
```

or

```
const pushError = (error) => {
    context.get('errors').push({
        status: 'err',
        message: 'There is an error',
        ts: new Date(),
        details: error
    })
}

try {
    ....
} catch(ex) {
    pushError(ex)
}

return msg;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, storing an error in the context does not add it to the debug sidebar